# Python mydict( Trying to read values from mydict)

Tags: python

I am trying to read values that were stored in mydict. I keep getting invalid response when running the program. The Excel sheet is formatted by year, location, id, power, and isload. My goal is to print the information associated all the information based off the year and location number.

[image: Excel Sheet]

```
data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
# read the entire CSV into Python.

# assume CSV has columns as described in the doc string
keyinput=input("Select Year of Study: ")
year=keyinput

mydict={"locA":1,"locb":2}
keyinput2=input(" Select the number associated to the TLA Pocket Location:")

if keyinput2 in mydict:
location=keyinput2
  else:
    print("Invalid Number")

for year,location,bus,change,isload in data:
    # convert the types from string to Python numbers

    change= float(change)
    bus = int(bus)

    if isload.isdigit() and int(isload):
        print()

    else:
        exit
```

Comment: please refrain from using links to pictures. Rather, just upload them directly to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are putting in a number (example 2) and expecting the dictionary to tell you if that value is in the dict or not. However the dictionaries "in" operator works on keys, not values.

Consider this:

```
mydict = {"a" : 1, "b": 2}
print("Is 1 in mydict? ", 1 in mydict)
print("Is a in mydict? ", "a" in mydict)
print("Is 1 in mydicts values? ", 1 in mydict.values())
```

Output:

```
Is 1 in mydict?  False
Is a in mydict?  True
Is 1 in mydicts values?  True
```

Keep in mind that asking whether a value is in a dict or not is a O(n) operation, the program may have to look at every value in order to determine if that value is in the dictionary or not. However asking if a key is in a dictionary is O(1) (very fast).

If you are always looking up the location based on the number, consider switching the keys/values of your dict around like this:

```
mydict={1:"locA",2:"locb"}
```

I don't know much about reading from an excel document or about the nature of the data you have, but assuming your for loop works, here is how you might load the values into the dict:

```
data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
mydict = {}
for row in data:
    year,location,bus,change,isload = row[0:5]
    # convert the types from string to Python numbers

    change= float(change)
    bus = int(bus)

    # If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
    if year not in mydict:
        mydict[year] = {}

    busses_in_year = mydict[year]
    if location not in busses_in_year:
        busses_in_year[location] = []

    # Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
    busses_in_year[location].append((bus, change, isload))

# assume CSV has columns as described in the doc string
year = input("Select Year of Study: ")

location = input(" Select the number associated to the TLA Pocket Location:")

if year in mydict and location in mydict[year]:
    busses_in_year = mydict[year]
    print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year: ")
    for bus in busses_in_year[location]:
        print(bus)
else:
    print("Invalid Year or Location")
```

Since you are using two keys to group/access the data, you can use nested dictionaries to solve this. Note the syntax to put things into and access things from a dictionary is `dict_name[key] = value` and `value = dict_name[key]` respectively.

Comment: Hey Aaron, is it possible for the key to be read off excel. My second column has the key values. I changed it up but it's still printing ()()()()()()()(). Is there another way to do this? and if there is how can I introduce more data into excel sheet so it can be read

Comment: It is printing that because your print statement is empty. I edited my answer with a best guess as to what you want. Please give an example input and expected output if I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: My goal is trying to read the Bus Number, change, and isload values based off Year and location. The isload values are the amount of buses in that one area, for example 2017, has 4 buses, so I would put 1,2,3,4 to read the amount of buses in area. I'm also working with PSSE. should I post that code for you to better understand. I am not the greatest at explaining things. Sorry

Comment: I created a dictionary of dictionaries, the outer dictionary groups everything by year, while the inner dictionary groups all the data by location within that year. So if you run the code above, and type in a year and a location, it will print out all the bus numbers/change/isload data accociated with that year and location.

Comment: I am receiving an error: Too many values to unpack. Does that Excel can't handle it or my excel sheet doesn't correspond to program

Comment: That is because your excel sheet has more columns than you are unpacking in the for loop. Either name all the columns in the for loop, change the excel spread sheet so it only has the data you need in it, or you can use a list to unpack the data.

Comment: I edited the above answer to show an example of how to unpack the first 5 columns of a given row.

Comment: ok the error is removed. The program is running but It keeps coming up as "Invalid Year or Location". Can I somehow send you my excel sheet?

Comment: What year and location are you putting in?

Comment: If you put in `2017` when it asks for the year, and `2` when it asks for the location, it should output results (just looking at the example input above).

Comment: Yes, I inputted 2017 and 2, and I am getting a result of "Invalid Year or Location"

Comment: Is there any columns in your spreadsheet before these columns you are interested in? Try printing out what is in mydict and see if you can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Are you using python 3 or 2? Because depending on the version input is going to be a string or an int respectively which could also be your problem.

Comment: after print mydict, this is the result {'2017': {'1': [(126607, 406.0, '1'), (126608, 389.0, '2'), (126614, 223.0, '3'), (126612, 463.0, '4')], '2': [(126607, 418.0, '1'), (126608, 430.0, '2'), (126614, 216.0, '3'), (126612, 472.0, '4')]}}

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: The issue is when you use input, it returns an integer, but the keys in the dictionary are strings (the year and location). So either use `raw_input("your message here")` to get the year and location, or cast the year and location to int like you did with bus.

Comment: it works, raw_input was the solution:                                                          Select Year of Study: 2017                                                                       Select the number associated to the TLA PocketLocation:1                                                    Output:                         (126607, 406.0, '1')
(126608, 389.0, '2')
(126614, 223.0, '3')
(126612, 463.0, '4')              THANK YOU SOO MUCH. If I have additional questions would you mind if I email you, I don't have the rep to chat on website

Comment: If they are unrelated to this then you should make another question on Stack Overflow. If your question is answered here you should accept it (by clicking the check mark) :)